# Trying to access children of custom AlertDialog results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, dialog, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view

I am experimenting with a custom `AlertDialog` in Android and stumbled over an `Exception` I do not understand.

I defined the custom `AlertDialog` in *res/layout/dialog_resident_next_dates.xml*

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_title"
    style="@style/customdialog_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="@color/grey3"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_content"
    style="@style/customdialog_paragraph"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In the method that triggers the `AlertDialog`, following is implemented

```
public void onClickResidentDates(View v){
    String datesOliva = "a (...) long (...) string";

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_resident_next_dates, null));
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();

    TextView dialogContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_content);
    dialogContent.setText(datesOliva);
}
```

This results in a `NullPointerException` on Line 364, more precisely

```
dialogContent.setText(datesOliva);
```

Why is this `Exception` thrown? The layout gets inflated properly (tested with empty `View`s), and the TextView should exist. Is there any problem that in this method, the `Dialog` is only built (I think that is neither the problem, since `.show()` should create the `AlertDialog`)?

**Note**: Since I do not exactly know how to fully create a custom AlertDialog, I used a little 'hack'. The whole custom layout xml gets set as title, while the default message View is set empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_resident_next_dates, null);
alert.setView(v);
TextView dialogContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_content);
dialogContent.setText(datesOliva);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current inflated layout. You inlfate a custom layout and you have text views there. So you need to use the view object to initialize your views.

Also

`public AlertDialog.Builder setCustomTitle (View customTitleView)`

Set the title using the custom view customTitleView.

So you probably need `alert.setView(v)`

`public void setView (View view)`

Set the view to display in that dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this-

```
public void onClickResidentDates(View v){
    String datesOliva = "a (...) long (...) string";

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_resident_next_dates, null);
    alert.setCustomTitle(view);
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();

    TextView dialogContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_content);
    dialogContent.setText(datesOliva);
}
```

Comment: Why is the id of a included View not globally visible?

Comment: Whenever you inflate a view dynamically in your Activity, then you have to hold that view so that you can find the id of its components in its context only.

Comment: View id is not globally visible since you are using it in an `Activity` and there you are inflating a layout. So by default all `findViewById()` will search for id's in activity's layout. Now in AlertDialog you are inflating another view and textView is part of alertDialog whereas without using `view.findViewById()` will make android search `textView` in main `layout`.

Comment: @Valentino Ru.... I hope, now it will be more clear to you as Rohan has explained it much better than me. :)